# Зависимый положения от камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d, математика

Этот вопрос связан с координатами. Использую Unity3d. Необходимо чтобы одна переменная зависела от другой в числовом промежутке.

Есть камера. Есть куб. Нужно:

1. Если камера по Y = -90 то у куба Y = -1.
2. Если камера по Y = 90 то у куба Y = 1.

Это начало и конец, если, допустим, Y камеры = 10, то у куба, например, Y = 0.12542434.

Надеюсь кто-нибудь понял и сможет мне помочь.

Comment: >Зависимый положения от камеры

>Надеюсь кто-нибудь понял

ну да, чего ж тут непонятного

Answer (score 1):

Есть одна сложная математическая формула, я тебе ее по секрету скажу.

`cam.y / 90 = cub.y`